# Validate Project Settings won't go away in XCode 4.4.1

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, xcode4.4

I am trying to get the Second Life Open Source Viewer to succeed compiling on 10.8.1 with XCode 4.4.1. I have managed to get it to run a few times but after cleaning my build folder, now the "Validate Project Settings" warning keeps popping up, telling me that I should change the compiler to the recommended one, Apple LLVM 4.0. However there are many compiler flags in my project that are incompatible with Clang. I must use GCC 4.2. So I uncheck all boxes and click Done, but then when I try to build again, I keep getting the same "Validate Project Settings" warning.

I think the only way I got it to go away before was by accepting it, letting it make all its changes, then reverting to the snapshot it makes before doing the changes. However this is a very time-consuming work-around, since creating the snapshot takes forever.

I was trying to find an option to "ignore compiler version" or "don't validate project settings" but I couldn't find any such option. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Set 'LastUpgradeCheck = 0440;' at pbxproj and also 'LastUpgradeVersion = "0440"' for each xcscheme in your project.
To be precise:
1. open your project.pbxproj with some text editor (e.g. XCode) and find the next block:

```
/* Begin PBXProject section */
        <somehash> /* Project object */ = {
            isa = PBXProject;
            attributes = {
                LastUpgradeCheck = 0440;
            };
            ...
        };
/* End PBXProject section */
```

Make sure LastUpgradeCheck is set to latest version (0440). It should look like:

```
<Scheme
   LastUpgradeVersion = "0440"
   version = "1.3">
```

2.open your *.xcscheme with some text editor and for the root element Scheme make sure its attribute LastUpgradeVersion is set to "0440" value.

1. Repeat for all projects in your workspace (Find&Replace, regexp and other batch edit tools may be useful).

If it doesn't help, you can try to validate project settings with Xcode, check diff with original project and scheme and manually revert options you care about, leaving aside all the others. Do it for one project and check if it helps. On success - make the same changes for all the other projects&schemes. This is the way I figured out the previous solution and it works for me just fine.
VCS with a fine diff tool would help a lot.

Comment: I also found deleting XCode caches helped majorly.

Comment: OK nevermind. That didn't really help. Your solution sucks, BTW, because there are... A METRIC CRAP TON of projects in my workspace. So this will take HOURS. Please God let Apple fix this terrible, horrific bug in their next update.

Comment: Is there a FAST way to do this? Apple will be done with the bug fix before I get done with this.

Comment: Well, actually I used XCode's Find with my workspace directory as a search path. And since it supports regexp, you can easily use find&replace.
And it was quite fast - a few minutes for couple of dozens of projects.

Comment: Problem is that there is no "LastUpgradeVersion" at all in the attributes. There is something that says compatibilityVersion = "XCode 3.2" ... do I need to change that as well?

Comment: Oh also isn't the latest version 0441?

Comment: No, compatibility version is something another, you can keep it as is. I updated the answer so you can see how root element looks like after upgrade. As for latest version: when I asked my XCode (4.4.1) to validate project, it set this values to 0440, not 0441. Don't know why :)

Comment: OK I put 0441 anyway. Maybe that's the bug. Anyway I'm sure it just checks to make sure it's equal to or greater than. Thanks for the tip about global search and replace in the project folder, that saved me hours (there were over 300 replacements to make). Testing now.

Comment: Didn't work. Still wants to Validate Project Settings. Still reverts the build settings of one of my targets back to 10.8 deployment target even after I set it to 10.6 every time before the build. I can only conclude that XCode 4.4.1 is a buggy piece of crap that will never work, and simply needs to be updated. Now my development machine's totally useless. Great.

Comment: Updated solution with more complex one. If it won't help either than maybe you really should blame xcode.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16333/discussion-between-commatoast-and-diplomat)

Comment: Your solution still doesn't work. If you have anything furhter do the chat thing I guess.